# Apache POI spoils Table Of Contents after replacing strings in doc file

Tags: apache-poi, doc, tableofcontents

I have to replace some strings in *.doc files. (I know it would be easier with *.docx) When I do more than one replace the Table Of Contents damages. Is there a way to preserve the Table Of Contents?

I have two pieces of code, which seems to create the same output.

the faster code:

```
Map<String, String> items = new HashMap<>();
items.put("toreplace1", "replacement1");
items.put("toreplace2", "replacement2");
try (POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("c:\\doc\\mydocument.doc")); HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);) {
    Range r1 = doc.getRange();
    items.forEach((k, v) -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < r1.numSections(); ++i) {
            Section s = r1.getSection(i);
            for (int x = 0; x < s.numParagraphs(); x++) {
                Paragraph p = s.getParagraph(x);
                for (int z = 0; z < p.numCharacterRuns(); z++) {
                    CharacterRun run = p.getCharacterRun(z);
                    String text = run.text();
                    if (text.contains(k)) {
                        run.replaceText(k, v);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    doc.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\doc\\mydocument_replaced.doc")));
}
```

the slower code:

```
Map<String, String> items = new HashMap<>();
items.put("toreplace1", "replacement1");
items.put("toreplace2", "replacement2");
try (HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File("c:\\doc\\mydocument.doc")))) {
    Range range = doc.getRange();
    items.forEach((k, v) -> {
        range.replaceText(k, v);
    });
    doc.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\doc\\mydocument_replaced.doc")));
}
```

Comment: This is reproducible if the string "toreplace1" is contained within a heading which is used in the TOC. And then it also occurs even if only that one string will be replaced. But since the binary file format `HWPF` really is **H**orrible**W**ord**P**rocessor**F**ormat, the best option you will have is filing a bug report to `apache poi`. Do this together with the shorter of your both codes and provide an example `mydocument.doc`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the damaging of `Word` fields (`TOC` also is a field), one could restrict the replacements only to document parts outside fields.

A field always starts with a run containing the bytes `0x13` and ends with a run containing the bytes `0x15`. So the following code should restrict the replacements only to document parts outside fields. Using this code the damaging of the `TOC` should be avoided. But of course the `TOC` then will not up to date and must be updated manually (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>F9</kbd>).

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class WordReplaceTextInHWPFRuns {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Map<String, String> items = new HashMap<>();
  items.put("toreplace1", "replacement1");
  items.put("toreplace2", "replacement2");

  boolean insideField = false;

  try (HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File("mydocument.doc")))) {

   Range range = doc.getRange();
   for (String k : items.keySet()) {
    String v = items.get(k);
    for (int r = 0; r < range.numCharacterRuns(); r++) {
     CharacterRun run = range.getCharacterRun(r);
     String text = run.text();

System.out.println(text);

     if (text.indexOf('\u0013') > -1) insideField = true;
     if (text.indexOf('\u0015') > -1) insideField = false;
     if (text.contains(k) && !insideField) {
      run.replaceText(k, v);

System.out.println("===========REPLACED=============");
System.out.println(run.text());

     }
    }
   }

   doc.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("mydocument_replaced.doc")));

  }
 }
}
```